# Telegram: Sen photo into a message without showing the photo link with Telegraf (NodeJs)

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegraf, telegram-api

I'm on a channel that sends messages that contains a text, with a link (that link has not an image) and an image (tip product from amazon):

[image]

I tried with this code and it's similar:

```
bot.telegram.sendMessage('mychannel', `Hello https:/path/to/image.jpg`)
```

And it works it similar, but it remains the link. SO how can i put that way with image preview but not the link?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround(trick) would be to insert the link but use an empty character unicode (like from https://emptycharacter.com/)

Here is an example (I inserted the [photo URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPKR5.png) with an empty character)
[image]

some sample code to get you started:

```
const Telegraf = require("telegraf");

const bot = new Telegraf(" ... ");

const CHAT_ID = ... ;

function getHiddenLink(url, parse_mode = "markdown") {
  const emptyChar = "‎"; // copied and pasted the char from https://emptycharacter.com/

  switch (parse_mode) {
    case "markdown":
      return `[${emptyChar}](${url})`;
    case "HTML":
      return `<a href="${url}">${emptyChar}</a>`;
    default:
      throw new Error("invalid parse_mode");
  }
}


// Option 1: sending with MARKDOWN syntax
bot.telegram.sendMessage(
  CHAT_ID,
  `
some test text in markdown
${getHiddenLink("https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPKR5.png", "markdown")}
`,
  {
    parse_mode: "markdown",
  }
);


// Another option: sending with HTML syntax
bot.telegram.sendMessage(
  CHAT_ID,
  `
some test text in HTML
${getHiddenLink("https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPKR5.png", "HTML")}
`,
  {
    parse_mode: "HTML",
  }
);
```

Here we just create a new function `getHiddenLink()` that accepts the URL and parse_mode (HTML or markdown) and just craft a new URL representation with the empty character as the link-text and return it.

Comment: You put the character before or after the link? Or you changed one link character?

Comment: @Mattia I've added a sample code and an explanation on how-to.. take a look please

Comment: Ok thank you i understand almost all, only a question. the parse_mode passed on the second parameter okay, but the other parameter on .sendMessage()? What's that? The real parse of the text?

Comment: the last argument on `sendMessage()` is actually how we pass paramaters to the bot API itself.  (we are telling the bot-api that we are sending a string that is formatted in either MD or HTML when we pass a JSON object with `parse_mode` key set.)

Comment: a curiosity, i can do it also with a local image? I've putted the path to the image instead of the link but it doesn't work

Comment: No, that wouldn't work. The picture has to be uploaded to some server first (this is just a link-preview afterall)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to send a preview without a link. You can try to have some by your own telegram account and you will see it is impossible.
Instead of preview, add some caption to photos.

Comment: Yes i know with caption, but using sendPhoto and seand directly it cover all the message. SO i would to create something like that, with a margin to the message frame limit